# Unable to switch back from tty1-tty6 to tty7?

Tags: debian, linux-mint

I'm using Linux Mint Debian Edition with Cinnamon. If I switch to another tty using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F#</kbd> and then switch back to tty7, I only see the terminal with this error:

```
[FAIL] startpar: services returned failure: plymouth ... failed
```

I checked in the dmesg, daemon.log, lastlog, messages, user.log, and Xorg.0.log and I don't see the error anywhere. I'm forced to switch back to another tty and restart mdm (Mint Display Manager) to get back to the log in screen (and thus losing whatever I was working on).

How do I fix this? I thought Plymouth was merely for setting the resolution as early as possible in the boot process. I did post a [similar thread](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=127255) at the LM forums, but haven't received any word yet.

Comment: Have you tried Alt-Left or Alt-Right?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco How did I miss that? That works perfectly, so post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried Alt-Left or Alt-Right?

(I don't use Debian, I found the info [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=509489). I'll try it on RHEL next time I'm on my Linux box.)

Comment: Interesting that you found the shortcut in a mostly unrelated bug report. How did you come across that?

Comment: Google'd "debian cinnamon x server tty" wondering if it was on a different tty number or something.

Comment: I had searched something similar, and searching again I can see that I simply glossed right over that. Clearly I need to get off EST and back on GMT.